# Image not uploading without submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to upload mp3 file to server without using submit button i am using ajax but file not uploading to server.Where i am wrong here is my code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fileToUpload').change(function(){
        var file_data = $('#fileToUpload').prop('files')[0];   
        var form_data = new FormData();                  
        form_data.append('file', file_data);
        $.ajax({
            url: "modules/phone/newvoicemail.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: form_data,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

In newvoicemail.php i put following code

```
$src = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $file_name = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
    $file_size =$_FILES['fileToUpload']['size'];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
    $file_type=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['type'];
    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"voicemail/".$file_name);
```

here is my html code

```
<form name="voicemailform" action="modules/phone/voicemail.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-inline for-frm">
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
</form>
```

Comment: Try using onInput instead of onChange.

Comment: _"file not uploading to server"_ is a bit broad for an error description. How far do you get? Does the ajax fire? Do you have data sent to the server? Do you receive any data _at_ the server?

Comment: You're also passing the file as `file`. You're first doing `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`, but then you're trying to fetch `$_FILES['fileToUpload'][...]` in the rest of the script. `fileToUpload` would be undefined.

Comment: here `form_data.append('file', file_data);` you give the filedata the name `file`, not `fileupload` (the name of the `<input type=file..>` won't be used here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Since you are uploading using ajax, you do not need `name`,`action`,
   `method` and `enctype` attributes on your HTML `form` tag. Same applies to `name` attribute of file input tag.
2. You need to add **enctype: 'multipart/form-data',** to **$.ajax({...});**
3. Since you are appending form data with param name **file** in JS as
   **form_data.append('file', file_data);**, you should access it in php
   as **$_FILES['file']** and not <del>$_FILES['fileToUpload']</del>

**HTML Code:**

```
<form class="form-inline for-frm">
    <input type="file" id="fileToUpload">
</form>
```

**JS Code:**

```
       $('#fileToUpload').change(function () {
            var file_data = $('#fileToUpload').prop('files')[0];
            var form_data = new FormData();
            form_data.append('file', file_data);
            $.ajax({
                url: "modules/phone/newvoicemail.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: form_data,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                processData: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });
```

**PHP Code: newvoicemail.php**

```
<?php
    $src = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($src, "./voicemail/".$file_name);
```