# Php $_FILES is empty when upload with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have form  with input for attachment:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post" id="sendInvoiceForm">
         .....
        <div class="templateDiv">
            <span class="invoice_email_label">Email attachments:</span>
            <input name="email_attachment[]" type="file" multiple="">
        </div>
        <div class="templateDiv">
            <button id="send_invoice_btn" class="bigButton redButton">Send</button>

        </div>
    </form>
```

And js:

```
                    data = new FormData($("#sendInvoiceForm")[0]);
                    data.append('flagSend', 1);
                    data.append('send_invoice_subject', sendInvoiceSubject);
               ....
     $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: data,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    url: sJSUrlSavePdfInvoiceToServer,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.msg === 'Error. This invoice number  exists.') {
                            alert(data.msg);
                        } else {
                            ...
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('error');
                    }
                });
```

I tested and seems it doesnt work. All data pass well,  but not file.
When I print_r $_FILES it is empty. What is my error? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image not uploading without submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51998733/image-not-uploading-without-submit-button)

Answer (score 1):

it's work for me --

```
 var form_data = new FormData($('#submitForm')[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url() . 'backends/update_documents' ?>",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json', // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: form_data,
            success: function (res) {
                // console.log(res);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                //console.log(xhr);
            }
        });
```

you can try with cache: false
and mention for button, type="button"

Answer (score 1):

this is what i do and works
append the formdata,

```
var formData = new FormData(your_form);
 // for multiple files , because i need to check
```

new_files is class, i use because i am creating form dynamically

```
$.each($(".new_files"), function (i, obj) {
//                console.log(obj.files);
        $.each(obj.files, function (j, file) {
              var max_size = 5120000;
              var file_type= file.type;
              var match = ["image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/jpg", "application/pdf"];
            // after validation etc
       //   append formdata
           formData.append('file[' + j + ']', file);
            });
  });
  // if you want something else, 
  formData.append("id", $('#kreditornr').val());
  // ajax

  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "url",
     data: formData,
     contentType: false, // The content type used when sending data to the server.
     cache: false, // To unable request pages to be cached
     processData: false, // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
       success: function (data) {
          // success
       }
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

First remove `dataType: 'json'` 
Then if it still shows error then replace

```
data = new FormData($("#sendInvoiceForm")[0]);
```

with

```
data = new FormData($("#sendInvoiceForm").prop('files')[0]);
```

Comment: Why? Passing the form element  to FormData should work just fine. And `dataType` is only relevant with regard to response

Comment: I have gone through same problem then after removing datatype my code worked

Answer (score -3):

try to send the data via :

```
 data: $('#sendInvoiceForm').serialize();
```

Comment: You can't serialize files